# Header of Community

Tags: html, customer-community

HTML Header of community is not working [image]

```
 <html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="/resource/communityResources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/resource/communityResources/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
    <link href="/resource/communityResources/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
     <link href="/resource/communityResources/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
    <link href="/resource/communityResources/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!--META TAGS-->
          <div  style="background-color:black;overflow:hidden;">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <a class="navbar-brand" style="line-height: 0px; padding: 10px 15px;" href="https://ecotour.force.com/members/CommunitiesLanding"><img height="30px" alt="EcoTours Logo"
                    src="/resource/communityResources/img/logo.png"/></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse" id="tabs">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                 <li> <a href="https://ecotour.force.com/members/CommunitiesLanding">Home</a> </li> 
                <li> <a href="https://ecotour.force.com/members/_ui/core/chatter/ui/ChatterPage">Collaborate</a> </li> 
               <li> <a href="https://ecotour.force.com/members/Answers">Answers</a> </li> 
               <li> <a href="https://ecotour.force.com/members/Requests">Requests</a> </li> 
               <li> <a href="https://ecotour.force.com/members/LogOutPage">Log Out</a> </li> 
               </ul> 
            </div>
        </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        $("#tabContainer").hide();
});
```

---

When I add full url like 
`<link href="https://na2.salesforce.com/resource/communityResources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`
 to static resource then it is working fine from internal salesforce but not when I log into salesforce community

Comment: I have a community where I use relative URLs to static resources for JS and CSS refs so I'm not quite sure what is happening here.

Comment: Might it be because your HTML in your documents folder is not externally available?

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into a similar issue. It looks like maybe relative tags for a community need to include the community name. Mine worked like this: `href="/community_name/resource/..."`